# Binding JQuery click behavior to Ajax returned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to bind a two-stage click behavior to paragraph elements returned from an ajax call. This is NOT a question about using on(), I get that. I'm trying to figure out why the second part of my statement isn't working.

HTML is:

```
<div class="lesson odd">
    <p class="lesson-text 25 lesson-selected">
        <input type="hidden" name="lesson-id" value="25360">
        <input type="hidden" class="lesson-day-number" value="25">
        <span class="lesson-name">25 Lovely Lesson Name</span>
        <span class="lesson-price">¥18,000</span>
        <br>
        <span class="lesson-short-name"></span>
        <span class="lesson-time">1:30pm - 3:30pm</span>
        <a class="lesson-details" href="#" data-hasqtip="2" oldtitle="Lovely description details" title="">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg lesson-desc-popup"></i>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

JQuery is:

```
// bind click function
// click on lesson to select, click again to de-select
jQuery('p.lesson-text').on("click", function() {

     if (jQuery(this).not('.lesson-selected')) {

          // reset all selections for this day
          var dayValue = jQuery(this).children().next('.lesson-day-number').val();
          jQuery('p.lesson-text.lesson-selected.' + dayValue).removeClass('lesson-selected');

          // add selected class
          jQuery(this).removeClass('deselected');
          jQuery(this).addClass('lesson-selected');

          // set all other lessons for that day to deselected
          jQuery('p.lesson-text.' + dayValue).not('.lesson-selected').addClass('deselected');


    } else if (jQuery(this).is('.lesson-selected')) {

          // reset all selections for this day, remove all deselected
          var dayValue = jQuery(this).children().next('.lesson-day-number').val();
          jQuery('p.lesson-text.lesson-selected.' + dayValue).removeClass('lesson-selected');
          jQuery('p.lesson-text.deselected.' + dayValue).removeClass('deselected');
    } 

}); // end click function
```

So the click behavior works fine for the first click. The user clicks on the lesson desired, and the "lesson-selected" class is added. If the user clicks on a different lesson, also no problem. The "lesson-selected" class is added, and all other lessons for that day are marked "deselected". So it seems the top part of the JQuery is working fine.

However, when I click on a p.lesson-text that already has the "lesson-selected" class, nothing happens. It should be clearing the class on that p.lesson-text, and clearing all the other "deselected" p.lesson-text elements as well. What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
<div class="lesson odd">
    <p class="lesson-text lesson-selected" day="25" lessonId="25360">
        <span class="lesson-name">25 Lovely Lesson Name</span>
        <span class="lesson-price">¥18,000</span>
        <br>
        <span class="lesson-short-name"></span>
        <span class="lesson-time">1:30pm - 3:30pm</span>
        <a class="lesson-details" href="#" data-hasqtip="2" oldtitle="Lovely description details" title="">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg lesson-desc-popup"></i>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>  

    $('.p.lesson-text').on("click", function () {
        var dayValue = $(this).attr("day");
        var lessonId= $(this).attr("lessonId"); 
        $(this).toggleClass('deselected').toggleClass('lesson-selected');
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I have a system-wide issue that makes me have to use jQuery instead of $. I've also used hasClass, the same problem remains: the second part of the JQuery statement does not work. When I click the same element the second time, nothing happens.

Comment: As a general rule for such, dont add a class once another is removed.

Comment: Use toggle to add or remove the lesson selected. Basicaly this class exist or not. If it does not exist it is obviously deselected. Try toggle with only one class

Comment: Toggle with one class? How would you write this, given my code above?

Comment: I am managing three views: selected, in orange, deselected, in grey; and fresh unselected, in white. So I can't just manage this with one class.

Comment: You can toggle as many class as you want.